# postgresql distinct not working

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, postgresql-8.4

I am using the following code for getting value from the database:

But when i wrote this code (testing as to see where the problem is..) i noticed the query is not fetching the distinct value out from the database:
Here is the query
  
  
`select distinct(ca.id)as id, acc.name as accName,pIsu.name as pareentIsu, sIsu.name as subIsu ,
dv.domain_value as contractType,acc.id as accId,dvct.domain_value as contractstatus

from contracts_account ca left join business_unit pIsu on ca.parent_isu_fk = pIsu.id

left join business_unit sIsu on ca.sub_isu_fk = sIsu.id

left join business_unit acc on ca.account_fk = acc.id

left join contracts con on con.contracts_account_fk = ca.id

left join domain_values dv on dv.id = con.contract_type_fk

left join domain_values dvct on dvct.id = con.contract_status_fk

where ca.id is not null  and con.contract_type_fk in ( 4466079 ) order by ca.id`

This query is simply not returning me **'Distinct Id**'
What am i doing wrong?
I am using postgres 8.2

Comment: `Select distinct col1, col2, col3 ...` will not return just distinct col1 values, it will return distinct col1 + col2 + col3 combinations

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your query is interpreted as:

```
select distinct (ca.id) as id, acc.name as accName, . . .
```

This is a standard `distinct` statement.  If you want just one row per `ca.id` with values from the first row (based on the `order by`), then use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (ca.id) ca.id, acc.name as accName, . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps trying to use PostgreSQL's DISTINCT ON syntax?

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

ie. missing the ON?